# How to avoid all code nodes to expand on project opening?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a C# project and some code pages have few thousand lines of code. I really like the idea of nodes in the code editor. I use it a lot and create many regions. But every time I open the project, all the nodes are expanded and I have to minimize them manually. It gets really annoying.

I have not found any help about this on internet nor in the options of VS. There must be a setting somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IDE, from the Tools menu click Options.  Alter default [Outlining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td6a5x4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) using

```
TextEditor->C#->Formatting->Advanced
```

There is a checkbox here you can use to set defaults for Outlining.  This is VC# 10 Express but similar in other versions.

Answer (score 3):

In the Options dialog onder `Text Editor --> C# --> Advanced`, there is an option "Enter outlining mode when files open". This should be checked.

Comment: Didn't know this; I'll use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you try the suggested change, you may be disappointed. According to [this C# PM](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpide/thread/76444615-2293-4cc0-9c4f-ac872d51ff06), who's responding to a similar complaint:

> It is a bit confusing, but the
>   behavior you're seeing is intended. 
>   The feedback that we received with VS
>   2003 was that we should persist the
>   outlining state of source files after
>   they have been closed and then
>   reopened.  **The option in Tools |
>   Option now effectively means what the
>   default behavior should be for a file
>   that you have never opened before.  It
>   has no effect on files that you have
>   opened previously**, since those files
>   already have a persisted outlining
>   state.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want be a smart ass here, but often if you have that huge code in one file, you have more than one logical unit and might be able to (ans should) split it. (Single Responsibility Principle).
For my share, I don't like the regions because they are hiding code and I prefer to see all of it.

Comment: It is in the particular case of a complex form that has about 100 controls, so I can't escape it. But your point is good, I'll reevaluate if I can refactor a little. Thanx

Comment: Ok, WinForm classes can get rather big. Maybe you can create multiple sub controls and add them to the form.